# canactivate guard angular 2

Tags: angular, canactivate

I have an angular app with two components "login" and "home". I want to guard the home component until user logs in.

I have a service which has a boolean variable "isUserLoggedIn". Based on the value of this variable, I guard my component.

**Network Service** -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkService {

private isUserLoggedIn = false;

constructor(private _http:Http) {

   }

getUserLoggedIn(){
     console.log("network service ... isUserLoggedIn = "+this.isUserLoggedIn);
     return this.isUserLoggedIn;
   }

setUserLoggedIn(){
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
     console.log("service layer : setUserLoggedIn called .... isUserLoggedIn = "+this.isUserLoggedIn);
  }
}
```

**My auth-guard code**

```
import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';
import { Router,CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{
    constructor(private networkservice:NetworkService, private router:Router){

    }

    canActivate(){
        console.log("canActivate called : userLoggedIn = "+this.networkservice.getUserLoggedIn());
        if(this.networkservice.getUserLoggedIn()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers : [NetworkService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private networkservice : NetworkService, private router: Router) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(value:any){
    console.log("user = "+value.username+" password = "+value.password);
    if(value.username == "user" && value.password == "user"){

      this.networkservice.setUserLoggedIn();
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);

    }
    else{
      alert("Username or Password did not match !!!");
    }
 }

}
```

**Router**

```
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'; 

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

**Finally my app module**

```
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

.....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    Ng2UploaderModule,
    routes
  ],
  providers: [NetworkService,AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For now I am using hard coded text for username and password.

My problem is that even after login component sets the "isUserLoggedIn" variable of the service to "true", the auth-guard still finds it as false. And hence I cannot navigate to "Home" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have multiple instances of the `NetworkService`, so each instance can have a different logged in state.

Services that are meant to be a singleton (single instance to service the whole app) should be added only in the providers array of your root `AppModule`.

Your problem is that you've also added the service to `LoginComponent`.  So, just delete this line from that component:

```
@Component({
  providers : [NetworkService] // <-- DELETE or this will create a new instance. 
})
```

Once that is gone, the `NetworkService` that gets injected in the constructor will be the same instance as the `NetworkService` that the `AuthGuard` queries.